# Android Firebase SDK Github Auth

Tags: android, firebase, github-api

I'm trying to use Firebase to authenticate github users in order to make calls to Github API.

I'm following this [Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/github-auth)

I'm not able to get user access token as said in docs examples.

```
authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken()
```

and then I'm not able to do the authentication

```
authWithGithub
```

getAccessToken method isn't available as you can see in the image 
[getAccessToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPE6D.png)

I've searched all the forums trying to find a solution, but I'm not able to.

I'm pretty new to it, so please, elaborate.

Is this github auth working?
If yes, how can I proceed?
If not, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this code to get accesstoken.

```
((OAuthCredential)authResult.getCredential()).getAccessToken();
```

Comment: It worked. Can you provide where I can found this information, please?

Comment: For retriving OAuth access token, you need `OAuthCredential` class which is child of `AuthCredential` class.


`// The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
 // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential.html